# Using XCode (Swift) to develop iOS app for school and label properties won't refresh

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am a reading teacher (I don't teach programming) at a school for students with LDs. We needed an app to flash 20 words in a random order for a set number of milliseconds, then black out the word for a set number of ms, then proceed through the list of 20 words. I dabbled in programming 15 years ago but have never developed an app.

The logic works ok, but I know there are better ways to do it - I just don't have time to learn all the ins and outs right now! My only problem is that the label won't update until the entire routine completes so no words show. I have tried a bunch of different techniques recommended on this site, but have not gotten anything to work. Is there a simple solution - seems like the layoutIfNeeded is a recommended technique but I don't seem able to implement correctly. 
Any help is appreciated!

```
@IBAction func cmdStart(_ sender: Any) {
   // the main logic  

    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()


    var x = arc4random() % 20;
    var i:Int = Int(x)
    var num = 0

    while num < 20 {
        num += 1
        self.lblDisplay.backgroundColor=UIColor.white

        while wordUsed[i] == 1
        {
            x = (arc4random() % 20)
            i = Int(x)
        }

        // output
        print ("word is \(wordList[i])")
        self.lblDisplay.text = wordList[i]
        self.lblDisplay.backgroundColor=UIColor.white
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        //delay based on slider
        let delTimeWord = (self.sldDelay.value)*1000
        usleep(useconds_t(delTimeWord))

        //blackOut duration based on slider
        let delTimeBlack = (self.sldVisible.value)*1000
        usleep(useconds_t(delTimeBlack))
        self.lblDisplay.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

        wordUsed[i]=1
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In an iOS application, you need to let the "event loop" run. This is a loop run by the operating system that checks for input events, refreshes the screen, and generally keeps everything going.  If you don't let the loop run, then an app "locks up" and stops doing anything.

The `cmdStart` method, which I assume is triggered by a button, is itself being called by the event loop.  Rather than running your own loop within that method, what you should do is have that method set some state and maybe start a timer that will do things later, and then return so that the event loop can keep running.

So those variables that you currently have in your `cmdStart` should probably be properties of the view controller.  Instead of calling `usleep`, start a timer that will fire at the appropriate time, and in the timer handler, do whatever the "next step" is.

You don't need to call `layoutIfNeeded`. Just set the label's text and color within your handler method, and when it returns the event loop will take care of updating the screen,

Sorry that I can't provide a complete example, but I'd recommend reading about `NSTimer` and looking for examples.

Comment: Thank you! I will give that a try - got a little more learning to do...